# Why iteration of list taking more time if java 8 stream feature use?

Tags: java, foreach, parallel-processing, java-8, parallel.foreach

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
            data.add("data" + i);
        }
        System.out.println("parallel stream start time" + System.currentTimeMillis());
        data.parallelStream().forEach(x -> {
            System.out.println("data -->" + x);
        });
        System.out.println("parallel stream end time" + System.currentTimeMillis());

        System.out.println("simple stream start time" + System.currentTimeMillis());
        data.stream().forEach(x -> {
            System.out.println("data -->" + x);
        });
        System.out.println("simple stream end time" + System.currentTimeMillis());

        System.out.println("normal foreach start time" + System.currentTimeMillis());
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("data -->" + data.get(i));
        }
        System.out.println("normal foreach end time" + System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
```

**Output**

parallel stream start time 1501944014854

parallel stream end time 1501944014970

simple stream start time 1501944014970

simple stream end time 1501944015036

normal foreach start time 1501944015036

normal foreach end time 1501944015040

**Total time taken**

Simple stream -> 66

Parellem stream -> 116

simple foreach -> 4

In many blogs written that parallelStream is executing by parallel by internally managed distributed task among thread and collect automatically..

But as per above experiment it is clearly notice that Parallel Stream taking more time then simple stream and normal foreach.

Why it is taking more time if it is executed parallel? Is it good to use in project as this feature is downgrading performance?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Agreed that manage thread and collecting data from thread also in case of "map" operation.. If parallel stream processing 10000000 and then it should take less time ideally... So should we avoid to use parallel stream.

Comment: While the base of your code is fast, you include a print in each iteration. A print is a veeeeery slow command, compared to other computations. Its like with regular I/O commands or even internet connections. So basically this print statements extremely dominate every other part of your time measurements. Together with that you always have an overhead that comes with managing multiple threads. But in most cases this overhead is smaller than the benefit of multithreading. But as said, your printing dominates everything, try to remove it for receiving more correct time measurements.

Comment: It's important to remember that parallelism is not free. For a simple loop like this, the overhead of parallelism outweighs the parallelism. When you get into more complex operations, the parallelism may start to outweigh the overhead.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut Obviously printing is synchronous but doubt is that why Parellem stream taking more time?

Comment: Also note that your resulting time difference is very small. It could be possible that it fools you and you do not see the differences of the code but rather other effects. As said the printing dominates, it could be possible that the console (where it prints to) was busy in the other command and thus blocked some *ms* which has nothing to do with the actual code. Also Java sometimes optimizes code and you also experience caching effects when doing similar stuff. That could also explain the difference to the last variant. Bottom line: Good timing measurements are very hard.

Comment: @CodeIdenti if it is synchronous, how can it be faster if you're required to run the most expensive operation (printing) in sequence?

Comment: @Zabuza, I tried to remove print statement from iteration for above three cases.. I put nothing inside foreach but still ParallelStream taking more time

I ran cases few times and found parallel stream taking 30 times more then normal for each..

So there is no reason that I/o operation taking more time in parallel stream

Comment: @CodeIdenti if you put nothing into a loop, the compiler just removes it. It's not so smart to do that in your stream and lambda code.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut Please see my above comment.. I tried that foreach iterating with no action.. but still Parallel stream taking more time.

Comment: @CodeIdenti your benchmark is completely flawed, come back with a proper benchmark and show the code. I have no clue what you mean by "normal foreach". If you use the for loop construct, the compiler will just remove it if it is empty.

Comment: @Zabuza Correct!! I tried with some complex logic inside iteration and parallel stream just completed in milliseconds while for loop(non java8) taking too much time.. Thanks for clearification

Comment: @ThomasJungblut code is already available in the question.. "normal foeach" is already mentioned in code. Review code first...

Comment: @ThomasJungblut As in comment also mentioned that normal foreach means (nonJava8)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because q

Answer (score 1):

1. Your tests are based on **I/O operations** (the most expensive operation)
2. If you want to use parallel streams you have to take the **thread creation time overhead** into account. So only if your operation benefits from that then use it (that is the case for heavy operations). If not, then just use normal streams or a regular for-loop.

---

**Basic rules for measurement:**

1. Don't use I/O operation.
2. Repeat the same test **more then just once**.

So if we have to re-formulate the test scenarios again, then we probably have a test helper class defined as follows:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.UUID;

public class Benchmark {

    public static <T> T performTest(Callable<T> callable, int iteration, String name) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Iteraion> map = new HashMap<>();
        T last = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < iteration; i++) {
            long s = System.nanoTime();
            T temp = callable.call();
            long f = System.nanoTime();
            map.put(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), new Iteraion(s, f));
            if (i == iteration - 1) {
                last = temp;
            }
        }
        System.out.print("TEST :\t" + name + "\t\t\t");
        System.out.print("ITERATION: " + map.size());
        long sum = 0l;
        for (String i : map.keySet()) {
            sum += (map.get(i).finish - map.get(i).start);
        }
        long avg = (sum / map.size()) / 1000000;
        System.out.println("\t\t\tAVERAGE: " + avg + " ms");
        return last;

    }

    public interface Callable<T> {
        T call() throws Exception;
    }

    static class Iteraion {
        Long start;
        Long finish;

        public Iteraion(Long s, Long f) {
            start = s;
            finish = f;
        }
    }
}
```

Now we can perform the same test more then once using different operation. The following code shows test performed using two different scenarios.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import static java.lang.Math.*;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            final int iteration = 100;
            final List<String> data = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
                data.add("data" + i);
            }

            /**
             * Scenario 1
             */
            Benchmark.performTest(new Callable<Void>() {

                @Override
                public Void call() throws Exception {
                    data.parallelStream().forEach(x -> {
                        x.trim();
                    });
                    return (Void) null;
                }

            }, iteration, "PARALEL_STREAM_ASSIGN_VAL");

            Benchmark.performTest(new Callable<Void>() {

                @Override
                public Void call() throws Exception {
                    data.stream().forEach(x -> {
                        x.trim();
                    });
                    return (Void) null;
                }
            }, iteration, "NORMAL_STREAM_ASSIGN_VAL");

            Benchmark.performTest(new Callable<Void>() {

                @Override
                public Void call() throws Exception {
                    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
                        data.get(i).trim();
                    }
                    return (Void) null;
                }
            }, iteration, "NORMAL_FOREACH_ASSIGN_VAL");

            /**
             * Scenario 2
             */
            Benchmark.performTest(new Callable<Void>() {

                @Override
                public Void call() throws Exception {
                    data.parallelStream().forEach(x -> {
                        Integer i = Integer.parseInt(x.substring(4, x.length()));
                        double d = tan(atan(tan(atan(i))));
                    });
                    return (Void) null;
                }

            }, iteration, "PARALEL_STREAM_COMPUTATION");

            Benchmark.performTest(new Callable<Void>() {

                @Override
                public Void call() throws Exception {
                    data.stream().forEach(x -> {
                        Integer i = Integer.parseInt(x.substring(4, x.length()));
                        double d = tan(atan(tan(atan(i))));
                    });
                    return (Void) null;
                }
            }, iteration, "NORMAL_STREAM_COMPUTATION");

            Benchmark.performTest(new Callable<Void>() {

                @Override
                public Void call() throws Exception {
                    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
                        Integer x = Integer.parseInt(data.get(i).substring(4, data.get(i).length()));
                        double d = tan(atan(tan(atan(x))));
                    }
                    return (Void) null;
                }
            }, iteration, "NORMAL_FOREACH_COMPUTATION");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

1. The first scenario performs the same test using the `trim()` method 100 times for a list that contains **10_000_000 elements** and therefore it uses a **parallel stream**, then a **normal stream** and last the old school **for loop**.
2. The second scenario performs some relatively heavy operations like `tan(atan(tan(atan(i))))` for the same list with the same technique as in the first scenario.

---

The results are:

```
// First scenario, average times
Parallel stream:  78 ms
Regular stream:  113 ms
For-loop:        110 ms

// Second scenario, average times
Parallel stream:  1397 ms
Regular stream:   3866 ms
For-loop:         3826 ms
```

---

Note that you can debug the above code, then you notice that for parallel streams the program creates **three extra threads** under name `[ForkJoinPool-1]`, `[ForkJoinPool-2]` and `[ForkJoinPool-3]`.

**Edit:**
The sequential streams and the **for-loop** use the **caller's thread**.

Comment: Also note that the benefit you get from parallelizing operations heavily depends on your operating systems **scheduler** and of course on the **amount of cores** your machine actually has. A single core machine will probably not benefit a lot of those techniques...

Comment: Sequential streams are executed on the caller’s thread, just like the `for` loop.

Comment: @Holger you're right, after several debugging now I'am certain that the sequential stream use the caller's thread. Maybe I've been confused by another suspended debugging session. thanks